# Devise email confirmation from localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, localhost, actionmailer

I am able to get the registration confirmation email to send out in deployment on Heroku, but when I try a registration on localhost:3000, I get the following error:

```
undefined local variable or method `confirmed_at' for #<User:0xb67a1ff0>
```

In my config/environments/production.rb file I have:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'xxxx.com' }
```

And I have an initializer file with the following format:

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
   :user_name => "xxxx@heroku.com",
   :password => "xxxxxx",
   :domain => "xxxx.com",
   :address => "smtp.sendgrid.net",
   :port => "xxx",
   :authentication => :plain,
   :enable_starttls_auto => true
};
```

What settings do I need to get the localhost working?

Thanks!

John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your local environment migrated? Does your user model have `:confirmable` in the devise call?  Does User.confirmed_at exist in your database (do you have any pending migrations)?

You should also probably add a stacktrace from your exception if you have one.

Comment: Ahh, you're right.  I ran rake db:drop db:create db:migrate and it's working fine now.  Will accept answer when I can.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're missing a confirmed_at field for your user model.

You may correlate this with your schema.rb file.